# Comparar campos de dos tablas distintas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día
Tengo una tabla llamada **PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS**

```
SELECT nId_Medicinas, nId_Cabecera, nId_Articulo, cDescripcion, nCantidad, nPrecio, nImporte, cEstado FROM PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS
```

Y otra tabla llamada **PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS_HISTORY** con campos iguales y solo se diferencian por el campo nId_Medicinas

```
SELECT nId_Medicinas, nId_Cabecera, nId_Articulo, cDescripcion, nCantidad, nPrecio, nImporte, cEstado FROM PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS_HISTORY
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que me arroje solo los valores distintos en este caso los campos que se modifican son: **nCantidad, nPrecio, nImporte**

El resultado esperado es el siguiente, ya que si se compara estos campos son los que se cambiaron
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora solo he logrado obtener los valores repetidos

```
SELECT mh.nId_Medicinas, mh.nId_Cabecera, mh.nId_Articulo, mh.cDescripcion, mh.nCantidad, mh.nPrecio, mh.nImporte, mh.cEstado FROM Proceso.PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS m INNER JOIN Proceso.PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS_HISTORY  mh ON m.nId_Cabecera = mh.nId_Cabecera WHERE ISNULL(m.nId_Cabecera, 'NULL') = ISNULL(mh.nId_Cabecera, 'NULL') AND ISNULL(m.nId_Articulo, 'NULL') = ISNULL(mh.nId_Articulo, 'NULL') AND ISNULL(m.cDescripcion, 'NULL') = ISNULL(mh.cDescripcion, 'NULL') AND ISNULL(m.nCantidad, 'NULL') = ISNULL(mh.nCantidad, 'NULL') AND ISNULL(m.nPrecio, 'NULL') = ISNULL(mh.nPrecio, 'NULL') AND ISNULL(m.nImporte, 'NULL') = ISNULL(mh.nImporte, 'NULL') AND ISNULL(m.cEstado, 'NULL') = ISNULL(mh.cEstado, 'NULL')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y que has intentado? agrégalo por favor  a tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia acabo de agregar el resultado que obtengo hasta el momento @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select P.nId_Medicinas, T1.*
from
(
 select nId_Cabecera, nId_Articulo, cDescripcion, nCantidad, nPrecio, nImporte, cEstado 
 from PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS
 except
 select nId_Cabecera, nId_Articulo, cDescripcion, nCantidad, nPrecio, nImporte, cEstado 
 from PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS_HISTORY
) T1
inner join PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS P on T1.cDescripcion = P.cDescripcion
```

Aqui se hace una consulta interna(subconsulta) y sobre esta subconsulta se hace una consulta general.

Dentro de la subconsulta se hace uso del **operador de conjuntos except**, este operador se utiliza para saber los elementos que hay en un conjunto que no existen en el otro conjunto, es decir aqui se utiliza para saber los registros que estan en la **tabla PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS** que no existen en la **tabla PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS_HISTORY** atendiendo por supuesto a los campos seleccionados dentro de la **clausula select**, para que el **operador except** funcione ambos conjuntos deben tener la misma cantidad de campos en el **select** y corresponder con el mismo tipo de datos, por eso aqui no pongo al **campo nId_Medicinas** ya que es un campo que tiene valores diferentes en ambas tablas.

Sobre esta subconsulta se hace una consulta general la cual se va a relacionar a traves de la **clausula inner join** con la **tabla PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS** por el **campo cDescripcion** cuyos valores tambien deben ser unicos y es entonces cuando podemos seleccionar el **campo nId_Medicinas** y el resto de los campos obtenidos en la subconsulta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu consulta es que estas validando por igualdad y con un operador `and`, por lo que tu consulta validara que todos los campos sean exactamente iguales.

En este caso tendrías que hacer tus validaciones por diferenciación y aplicando el operador `or`, para que te arroje desde un solo campo que se modifique y no los 3.

```
SELECT  mh.nId_Medicinas
    , mh.nId_Cabecera
    , mh.nId_Articulo
    , mh.cDescripcion
    , mh.nCantidad
    , mh.nPrecio
    , mh.nImporte
    , mh.cEstado
FROM Proceso.PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS m
    INNER JOIN Proceso.PRESUPUESTO_MEDICINAS_HISTORY  mh ON m.nId_Cabecera = mh.nId_Cabecera
WHERE (
    ISNULL(m.nCantidad, 'NULL') != ISNULL(mh.nCantidad, 'NULL')
    OR ISNULL(m.nPrecio, 'NULL') != ISNULL(mh.nPrecio, 'NULL')
    OR ISNULL(m.nImporte, 'NULL') != ISNULL(mh.nImporte, 'NULL')
)
```

Por cierto mencionas que solo esos campos cambian por lo que son los unicos que agregue a la validación.